# Opening a .jnlp file in Java 8 without a certificate

Tags: java, security, java-8, jnlp

I'm a student trying to open a .jnlp file to run a linux desktop from a school managed website. I have no experience doing this. It is a java application, and it appears to have an invalid certificate. I added the host website to the exempt sites list on the java control panel, but I continue to get blocked for the same reason:

> Your security settings have blocked an application signed with an
>   expired or not-yet-valid certificate from running.

I entered the locations into the exempt list, but it continues to appear with the same reason for failure. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Surely all users of that website must have that problem, get them to use a currently valid certificate

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* Use a valid code signing certificate (one issued by a CA). I don't believe Oracle supports unsigned or self-signed code in any form, any longer.

Comment: Yeah I ended up downloading Java 7 and deleted Java 8 runtime and software developement. It runs on medium security on Java 7.

Comment: That led to problems with my eclipse though, so it can only be a temporary solution. I will talk to my professor about updating his program so this doesn't have to happen.